# Display Account Records Using Remoteaction?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am trying to display list of account records using remote action method i did using button tag but i need while page loading need to display all account records like if we query list of records in constructor in apex controller it will call when page loading display the records Same using remote action  method how it is possible if any one did same scenario please help to find the requirement..

Controller:

```
public class exremote {
    public static list<account> listacc{get;set;}
    @remoteaction
    public static list<account> getaccounts(){
        listacc = [select id,name,accountnumber from account];
        return listacc;
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="exremote">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function getallaccounts(){
    exremote.getaccounts(
    function(result,event){

     var html = '<table>';
               html = html + '<tr><td><b>Name :</b></td>';
               html = html + '<td><b>Industery:</b></td></tr>';
               if(event.status){
                 debugger;
               for (var prop in event.result) { 
               html = html + '<tr><td>'+event.result[prop].Name+'</td> <td>'+event.result[prop].AccountNumber+'</td></tr>';
               }
                html = html + '</table>';
                $("#accountDetails").html(html);
                x.style.visibility = "hidden";
               }
               else {
                 alert(event.message);
          }
    },{escape:true}
    );
    }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="getaccounts" onclick="getallaccounts();" />
        <div id="accountDetails"  >

        </div>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="getaccounts" onclick="getallaccounts();" />
```

instead of this do this

```
<script>

    getallaccounts();

</script>
```

Just call the method from script tag and it will work on load.